# Enabling SSL on webserver running on AWS EC2/Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-application-load-balancer

I currently have a docker container hosted on ec2 and running a web server. The IP Address resolves perfectly when running it with just the IP address not using https but, when I put in the DNS it does not work. I am currently have the node port mapped to port 80 in the initial dockerfile. Then I mapped port 80 to port 443 in hopes on creating a Load Balancer using a certificate from ACM. This is not a docker issue and I was hoping someone had some insight on how to configure a Load Balancer to use SSL to talk back to my web server that has port 80 exposed. When putting domain.io:443 I get the nginx screen.

Answer (score -1):

> configure a Load Balancer to use SSL to talk back to my web server that has port 80 exposed.

For that you require to setup HTTPS in your target group, not HTTP. Also it requires **self-signed certificate SSL** on the container to server the HTTPS traffic.

Comment: Do I have to add the self signed cert to the instance? Put it in same directory as Dockerfile?

Comment: Does the cert I add on the instance have to be added to the ALB as a "trusted backend cert"?

Comment: @aroe nginx must be serving it. So if you run nginx from the container, then you have to serve it from there. ALB does not check validity of the certificates. Just specifying port 443 and HTTPS in your target group should be enough. There are many tutorial how to setup end-to-end SSL on alb (e.g. [here](https://locusinnovations.com/2018/05/23/aws-end-to-end-ssl-encryption-with-an-application-load-balancer/)).

Comment: Isn't the self signed cert exactly what ACM takes care of?

Comment: @aroe No. ACM certs are public ones and they can't be used on instances or docker. ACM certs can only be used on load balancer, cloud front disto or API gateway. You need to have your own SSL cert if you want end-to-end encryption. But are you sure you require end-to-end ssl encryption? usually people don't do this.

Comment: no I don't think I want to require it, that's a good point. All I want to do is configure my container port correctly so it can be served on HTTPS. And I'm not sure if I need Nginx for that or not.

Comment: @aroe Then you don't have to worry about SSL on your containers. Usually what people do is: client---HTTPS---->ALB----HTTP---->ECS. If this setup does not work, you have to post your target group settings in question.

Comment: ahh ok so, my container is on an ec2 instance